# Salesforce lightning setting slds column rows to be the same height

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform, column, slds-grid, height

I'm using lightning:recordEditForm with lightning:inputField to generate a list of fields. I dynamically create a lightning:inputField component and add it to an slds column. The lightning:recordEditForm places the label of checkbox fields next to the checkbox which throws off all of the formatting. See image for example:

[image]

Is there a way to keep the spacing consistent with checkboxes? I don't care about getting the label above the checkbox, I just want to keep the spacing between each field consistent.

lighting:inputField Component:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="divId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="inputFieldId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="fieldName" type="String"/>
    <div aura:id="{!v.divId}">           
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="{!v.inputFieldId}" fieldName=" {!v.fieldName }" />
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Here is where the component exists in my base component:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm" recordId="{!v.CallTrackingId}" objectApiName="CallTracking__c" onsubmit="{!c.saveCallTracking}" >
        <lightning:button variant="brand" name="save" type = "submit" label="Save" class="slds-m-top_medium"/>
        <lightning:button variant="brand" name="cancel" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.closeCallTracking}" class="slds-m-top_medium"/>
        <lightning:messages />           
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters slds-cell-wrap ">                  
            <div class="slds-col slds-p-horizontal_medium" >  
                {!v.editFields1}
            </div>         
            <div class="slds-col">
                {!v.editFields2}
            </div> 
                </div>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Here is where I create the component in the helper:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(editFieldsToRender.length/2); i++) 
        {    
            $A.createComponent
            (
                "c:LightningInputFieldWithDiv",
                {
                    "divId": editFieldsToRender[i]+"Div",
                    "inputFieldId": editFieldsToRender[i],
                    "fieldName": editFieldsToRender[i]+"__c"
                },
                function(newInputField)
                {
                        editFields1.push(newInputField);
                        component.set("v.editFields1", editFields1);
                }
            );
        }
```

Any suggestions on keeping the row heights consistent would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @ztrition. How would you like the checkbox to be displayed on the page?
Would you prefer the checkbox to be aligned with the input field on the left?

Comment: I want the checkbox to be aligned with the field on the left. Moreso, I need the spacing around the element to be the same, so if I added another field underneath it it would also continue to line up fine.

Answer (score 1):

fyi: the field is aligned with the component's label, you will need to add padding or a marginf for checkbox types.

Additionally, you will probably want to use lightning:layout components for a better styling and uniformity of spacing amongst the different components you are rendering, for example:

```
<lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
        <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small">
            <div class="custom-box">1</div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small">
            <div class="custom-box">2</div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small">
            <div class="custom-box">3</div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small">
            <div class="custom-box">4</div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small">
            <div class="custom-box">5</div>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
```

you can easily control the sizing and padding in between items with the above approach.

so, you can replace

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters slds-cell-wrap ">                  
        <div class="slds-col slds-p-horizontal_medium" >
```

with the aformentioned components

one thing i did notice, is that for the checkbox to fully allign with your requirements, a top margin/padding would need to be added to the layoutItem:

markup example in a lightning app:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
        <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
            <lightning:input name="input1" label="Enter some text" />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
            <lightning:input name="input1" label="Enter some text" />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
            <lightning:input name="input1" label="Enter some text" />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small" class="slds-m-top_large">
            <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Basic option" name="input1"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
</aura:application>
```

[image]

Comment: Your example looks good. Can this be used with lightning:recordEditForm? I see you are using lightning:input does that work instead of lightning:inputField?

Comment: you can, however, the level of effort will be considerably higher, since you will later need to assign the values of the input fields to the lightning:inputfields manually